# Can we write a .setOnAction() into another .setOnAction() block in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I am a beginner in Java since I took my first programming class last semester and I am trying to keep practicing this summer. I was working on something very basic and simple but I figured out I had a problem.

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);


scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("My little success story");


        TextInputDialog entername = new TextInputDialog("Your name");
        entername.setTitle("Player Information");
        entername.setHeaderText("What is going to be the name of the `person we'll follow?");`
        entername.setContentText("Please enter your name:");

        Optional<String>result = entername.showAndWait();
        if (result.isPresent()){
            name = result.get();
        }


        Image roleplay1 =new Image("Roleplay - 1.jpg");
        ImageView image1A = new ImageView();

        image1A.setImage(roleplay1);
        image1A.setFitHeight(400);
        image1A.setFitWidth(400);
        image1A.setSmooth(true);
        root.getChildren().add(image1A);

        Label welcome = new Label("Welcome "+name+" it's 2:00 `p.m."+newLine`
                +"You either can go to your bio class or to the gym.");

        HBox HWelcome = new HBox(welcome);
        HWelcome.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);
        HWelcome.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #faffff");

        Button goToClass = new Button("Go to class");
        goToClass.setPrefWidth(120.);

        Button goToGym = new Button("Go to the gym");
        goToGym.setPrefWidth(120.);

        HBox choice = new HBox(goToClass, goToGym);
        choice.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);
        choice.setSpacing(70.);
        choice.setPadding(new Insets(30));

        root.setBottom(HWelcome);
        root.setCenter(choice);


        goToClass.setOnAction(new EventHandler <ActionEvent>(){

            public void handle1(ActionEvent e){

                BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
                Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);


scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
                primaryStage.setScene(scene);
                primaryStage.setTitle("Roleplay");

                Image roleplay2A = new Image("Roleplay - 2A.jpg");
                ImageView image2A = new ImageView();

                image2A.setImage(roleplay2A);
                image2A.setSmooth(true);
                image2A.setFitHeight(400.);
                image2A.setFitWidth(400.);
                root.getChildren().add(image2A);

                Label scenario = new Label("You've arrived to class in `time."+newLine+`
                        "You are lucky, it was very important `today."+newLine+`
                        "You can team up with your best friend or with `the nerd.");`

                HBox HinClass = new HBox(scenario);
                HinClass.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);
                HinClass.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #faffff");

                Button yourFriend = new Button("Your friend");
                yourFriend.setPrefWidth(120.);

                Button theNerd = new Button("The nerd");
                theNerd.setPrefWidth(120.);

                HBox choice = new HBox(yourFriend, theNerd);
                choice.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);
                choice.setSpacing(70.);
                choice.setPadding(new Insets(30));


                root.setBottom(HinClass);
                root.setCenter(choice);


            }

            yourFriend.setOnAction(new EventHandler <ActionEvent>(){

                public void handle(ActionEvent e){

                            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
                            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);


scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
                            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
                            primaryStage.setTitle("Roleplay");

                            Image image = new Image("Roleplay 3 - `A.jpg");`
                            ImageView img = new ImageView(image);
                            root.getChildren().add(img);
                            img.setSmooth(true);

                        }

                    });


        });
```

So everything goes fine when I use my first button with

```
    goToClass.setOnAction(new EventHandler <ActionEvent>(){
```

But then, when I try to continue using the same technique of creating a new window with two buttons every time the user clicks on a button with this code

```
   yourFriend.setOnAction(new EventHandler <ActionEvent>(){
```

it says that there is some kind of syntax error and I can't go further.

I really don't know if I've been clear since this is my first question posted here but I hope you guys will be able to help me!

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested your code, but I only intend to help you eliminate the compilation errors as you say you're a Java beginner

```
package com.test;

import java.util.Optional;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextInputDialog;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Random
{
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        try
        {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setTitle("My little success story");

            TextInputDialog entername = new TextInputDialog("Your name");
            entername.setTitle("Player Information");
            entername.setHeaderText("What is going to be the name of the `person we'll follow?");
            entername.setContentText("Please enter your name:");

            Optional<String> result = entername.showAndWait();
            String name = "";
            if (result.isPresent())
            {
                name = result.get();
            }

            Image roleplay1 = new Image("Roleplay - 1.jpg");
            ImageView image1A = new ImageView();

            image1A.setImage(roleplay1);
            image1A.setFitHeight(400);
            image1A.setFitWidth(400);
            image1A.setSmooth(true);
            root.getChildren().add(image1A);

            Label welcome = new Label("Welcome " + name + " it's 2:00 `p.m." + System.lineSeparator() +
                "You either can go to your bio class or to the gym.");

            HBox HWelcome = new HBox(welcome);
            HWelcome.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);
            HWelcome.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #faffff");

            Button goToClass = new Button("Go to class");
            goToClass.setPrefWidth(120.);

            Button goToGym = new Button("Go to the gym");
            goToGym.setPrefWidth(120.);

            HBox choice = new HBox(goToClass, goToGym);
            choice.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);
            choice.setSpacing(70.);
            choice.setPadding(new Insets(30));

            root.setBottom(HWelcome);
            root.setCenter(choice);

            goToClass.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
            {

                Button yourFriend = new Button("Your friend");

                public void handle(ActionEvent e)
                {

                    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
                    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
                    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
                    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
                    primaryStage.setTitle("Roleplay");

                    Image roleplay2A = new Image("Roleplay - 2A.jpg");
                    ImageView image2A = new ImageView();

                    image2A.setImage(roleplay2A);
                    image2A.setSmooth(true);
                    image2A.setFitHeight(400.);
                    image2A.setFitWidth(400.);
                    root.getChildren().add(image2A);

                    Label scenario = new Label("You've arrived to class in `time." + System.lineSeparator() +
                        "You are lucky, it was very important `today." + System.lineSeparator() +
                        "You can team up with your best friend or with `the nerd.");

                    HBox HinClass = new HBox(scenario);
                    HinClass.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);
                    HinClass.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #faffff");

                    yourFriend.setPrefWidth(120.);

                    Button theNerd = new Button("The nerd");
                    theNerd.setPrefWidth(120.);

                    HBox choice = new HBox(yourFriend, theNerd);
                    choice.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);
                    choice.setSpacing(70.);
                    choice.setPadding(new Insets(30));

                    root.setBottom(HinClass);
                    root.setCenter(choice);

                    yourFriend.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
                    {
                        public void handle(ActionEvent e)
                        {

                            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
                            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
                            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
                            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
                            primaryStage.setTitle("Roleplay");

                            Image image = new Image("Roleplay 3 - `A.jpg");
                            ImageView img = new ImageView(image);
                            root.getChildren().add(img);
                            img.setSmooth(true);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }
}
```